# Simple create a case in Experience Cloud

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, experience-cloud

So I am extremely new when it comes to working with @wire and @track. I have tried to use the code from the web (But it is older due to the @track decorator). I would like to also refactor the code with the @wire.

I am trying to create a case from an account management page within an Experience Cloud site.

Can someone please let me know why this code doesn't do anything?

```html
<template>
  <h1>Create a new case</h1>
  <lightning-card title={title} icon-name="standard:record">
      <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
          <lightning-input label="Case Subject" onchange={handleChange} class="slds-m-bottom_x-small"></lightning-input>
          <lightning-input label="Case Description" onchange={handleChange} class="slds-m-bottom_x-small"></lightning-input>
          <lightning-button label={buttonlabel} variant="brand" onclick={submitCase}></lightning-button>
      </div>
  </lightning-card>
</template>
```

```js
import {
  LightningElement,
  track,
  api
} from 'lwc';
import {createRecord} from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import {ShowToastEvent} from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import CASE_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Case';
import SUBJECT_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Case.Subject';
import DESC_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Case.Description';
import STATUS_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Case.Status';
import ORIGIN_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Case.Origin';

export default class WealthCreateCaseDemo extends LightningElement {

  @api title;
  @api buttonlabel;

  @track subject = '';
  @track desc = '123234345345';

  handleChange(event) {
      if (event.target.label === 'Case Subject') {
          this.subject = event.target.value;
      }
      if (event.target.label === 'Case Description') {
          this.desc = event.target.value;
      }
  }
  submitCase() {
      const fields = {};
      fields[SUBJECT_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.subject;
      fields[DESC_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.desc;
      fields[STATUS_FIELD.fieldApiName] = 'New';
      fields[ORIGIN_FIELD.fieldApiName] = 'Web';

      const recordInput = {
          apiName: CASE_OBJECT.objectApiName,
          fields
      };
      createRecord(recordInput)
          .then(result => {this.dispatchEvent(
                          new ShowToastEvent({
                              title: 'Success',
                              message: 'Case is submitted : ' + this.case.id,
                              variant: 'success',
                          }),
                      );
              })
          .catch(error => {
              this.dispatchEvent(
                  new ShowToastEvent({
                      title: 'Error creating record',
                      message: error.message,
                      variant: 'error',
                  }),
              );
          });
  }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="helloWorld">
    <apiVersion>47.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <masterLabel>Case Create</masterLabel>
    <targets>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
            <property name="title" type="String" default="Submit Case"></property>
            <property name="buttonlabel" type="String" default="Submit Case"></property>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: Have you already considered using the [Create Case Form](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.rss_case_creation.htm&type=5) plus a quick action to do this?  Then you wouldn't need an LWC at all.

Answer (score 0):

When in the `.then()` block it tries to create the toast event, `this.case` is undefined, so trying to read the property `id` results in an error like

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')

If you want to show the id of the newly created record, you should use `result.id`

```js
createRecord(recordInput)
    .then((result) => {
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Success',
                message: 'Case is submitted: ' + result.id,
                variant: 'success'
            })
        );
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Error creating record',
                message: error.message,
                variant: 'error',
            }),
        );
    });
```

By the way, there is no need to use `@track` for `subject` and `desc`.
Moreover if you want to have a single `handleChange` method, you could add a [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) attribute with the name of the instance property to the lightning-input element, this way you will be able to avoid the if-else block:

**HTML**

```html
<lightning-input data-property="subject" label="Case Subject" onchange={handleChange} class="slds-m-bottom_x-small"></lightning-input>
<lightning-input data-property="desc" label="Case Description" onchange={handleChange} class="slds-m-bottom_x-small"></lightning-input>
```

**JS**

```js
handleChange(event) {
    const propertyName = event.target.dataset.property;
    this[propertyName] = event.target.value;
}
```

Please note that you could also use a [lightning-record-form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-form/documentation) or a [lightning-record-edit-form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation) to create a new record. Take a look at [Create a Record](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/data-create-record.html) documentation page.